# Is the sentence *I had my skills improved considerably* correct?

Tags: grammar, expression-choice, adverb-position

Could you please explain to me if the following sentence is correct?

Does it sound good?

> *Your training was very useful for me. I had my skills improved considerably.*

Or I must use something like:

> *Your training was very useful for me. I have considerably improved my skills of skiing.*

Which of the sentences is better if the first on is correct?

Comment: There is a difference between *is it correct* and *which one is better*. And please tell us why you think it might be incorrect.

Comment: My skiing abilities have improved considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both

> I had my skills improved considerably.

and

> I have considerably improved my skills.

are grammatically correct and acceptable English.

> ...skills of skiing.

would sound strange to a native speaker, although they would know what you mean.

> ...skills in skiing.

would sound better. The most common construction would be:

> I have considerably improved my skiing skills.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
It is important for me to get an answer from a native speaker.

Comment: Could you explain one more thing?
If the event was a long time ago (a year) and skills might be decreased. Is it correct to use the second sentence?

I may not be having such level of skills now.

Comment: "I had my skills improved" might technically be grammatical but being passive as it is sounds odd to me, like your skills were improved via a Matrix-like upload rather than practicing.

Comment: _Had my skills improved_ is rather unidiomatic. I had my car washed, my hair cut, and my skills improved?

Comment: @PavelN Yes, your skills were improved, even if they have decreased since.

Answer (score -2):

There is nobody that can improve your skills but yourself. Therefor, I do not think the first option is correct.

The second one contains two sentences that could be seen as not coupled at all. I assume that is not your intention.

I'd suggest something like this:

> Your training was very useful for me. It helped me to improve my
>   skills of skiing considerably.

Comment: There's no grammatical restriction that 'nobody that can improve your skills but yourself", and many people would disagree with it as a statement.